# How to extract different parts of a double in Java

Tags: java

// enters a price

```
double price = in.nextDouble();
int pennies = (int) Math.round(price *100);

int cents;
int dollars;
```

How would I be able to spilt the double pennies into two different parts? Thanks

EDIT:

One day soon, the US government will finally decide to do away with pennies, as they currently cost more than a penny to produce. Complete the program below so that it prompts the user for a price in dollars and cents, determines the cents portion of the price to the nearest dime, and prints the revised price.

For example, if a price was $32.56, the revised price would be $32.60. However, if a price was $23.34, the revised price would be $23.30.

Complete the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/** 
   This program reads a price in dollars and cents,
   rounds the price to the nearest dime,
   and prints out the revised price.
*/
public class NearestDime
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.print("Please enter the price: ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      double price = in.nextDouble();
      int pennies = (int) Math.round(price * 100);

      // Determine dollar and cents worth of pennies 
      int cents;
      int dollars;

      // Your work here     

      // Round cents to nearest dime
      int dimes;

      // Your work here     

      // Print revised price
      double revised = dollars + dimes * 0.1;
       System.out.printf("%.2f\n", revised);      
   }
}
```

This is the entire problem. Sorry for all of the confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by **two different parts**?

Comment: Like say the price was $3.49. In pennies that's 349. How do i get it where i can split it into dollars and cents after the rounding the pennies to 350.

Comment: int dollars = Math.floor(price); double cents = price % dollars; cents *= 100;

Comment: Based on your example it looks like you may be looking for modulo operator: `%100` but that is just a guess. You should update your question with proper example of inputs, expected output, and explanation why such output is expected.

Comment: @mynawaz Please don't answer questions in comments. Comments are for clarifying the questions. Answers are for answering.

Comment: Don't use floating point for money amounts, if you want to spare yourself nasty surprises with rounding turning up later.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment if you're looking for rounding off the currency, you can use BigDecimal which has many options to scale the precision.

```
    String curr = "1000.46243242"; // or double
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(curr);
    double d = bigDecimal.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).doubleValue(); // 1 --> digits after dot, 2nd argument --> precision type 
    System.out.println(d);
```

Refer doc for other rounding constants

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `double` to store monetary values. If you must use `double` to store monetary value, please reconsider, and *do not use `double` to store monetary values*!!

The reason is the following: monetary values are decimal values, whereas `double`s (and `float`s) are stored in binary. Unfortunately, not all decimal values have exact binary representations. For example, `0.10` cannot be exactly represented in binary (just like `1/3` cannot be exactly represented in decimal). You may not notice this immediately if you print the values, because `System.out.println` does some rounding and often rounds to the expected result, but at some point the errors will add up and you get unexpected results.

Instead, use `BigDecimal` to store monetary values. This class also has methods that you need to split your value in two parts:

```
BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal("2.56");
BigDecimal[] parts = price.divideAndRemainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
System.out.println("Dollars: " + parts[0]);
System.out.println("Cents: " + parts[1]);
```

If you really want the number of cents, replace the last line by:

```
System.out.println("Cents: " + parts[1].movePointRight(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a double price = 2.349 you can do:

```
int dollar = (int)Math.ceil(price) = 2
double cents = price - dollar = 0.349

or int cents = (int)((price - dollar)*100)
```

Is it what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int cents = (int) pennies % 100;
int dollars = (int) (pennies - cents) / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    double pennies = Math.round(price * 100);
    int dollar = (int) pennies / 100;
    double cent = pennies - dollar * 100;
```

Something like this?